# Give EKS service a static IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-route53, amazon-eks

When I delete an EKS/Kubernetes service and then create a new one - I believe the ingress hostname changes. The service is a load balancer - but we give at DNS name (CNAME) which points to the ingress hostname...so instead having to update Route 53 when we change the service, is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

So in short you can't avoid that. When you create a new EKS it will have to generate a new load balancer. Additionally, such NLB doesn't live in your account as the EKS is a managed service.

> The cluster control plane is provisioned across multiple Availability
>   Zones and fronted by an Elastic Load Balancing Network Load Balancer.
>   Amazon EKS also provisions elastic network interfaces in your VPC
>   subnets to provide connectivity from the control plane instances to
>   the worker nodes.